# How to catch failed message publish (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

what would be the best way to catch an error on `basic_publish()` method?

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/.   autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
$msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use try-catch methods

```
    ...
    try {
        $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
    } catch (Error $e) {
        // do something
    }
```